# Having trouble implementing history feature for tic tac toe using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently trying to do the Tic Tac Toe project using hooks. I'm having problems with implementing the "history" functionality:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.scss";

const App = props => {
  const [turn, setTurn] = useState("X");
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([Array(9).fill(null)]);
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState(null);

  const latestBoard = history[history.length - 1];

  const handleClick = i => {
    if (latestBoard[i] !== null) {
      return;
    }

    latestBoard.splice(i, 1, turn);
    setHistory([...history, [...latestBoard]]);
    setTurn(turn === "O" ? "X" : "O");
  };

  const handleHistory = index => {
    if (index === 1) {
      setHistory([Array(9).fill(null)]);
      return;
    }

    let newHistory = history.slice(0, index);
    setHistory(newHistory);
    console.log(history);
  };

  const calcWinner = squares => {
    /*...*/
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <GameBoard onClick={idx => handleClick(idx)} squares={latestBoard} />
      <Sidebar
        winner={winner}
        turn={turn}
        history={history}
        goBack={idx => handleHistory(idx)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const GameBoard = ({ squares, onClick }) => {
  const grid = squares.map((item, idx) => {
    return (
      <div key={idx} onClick={() => onClick(idx)}>
        {item}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div className="grid-container">{grid}</div>;
};

const Sidebar = ({ winner, turn, history, goBack }) => {
  let historyList = history.map((pos, idx) => {
    return idx >= 1 ? ( 
      <li key={idx} onClick={() => goBack(idx)}>
        {idx}
      </li>
    ) : null;
  });

  let info;

  if (winner) {
    info = `The winner is ${winner}`;
  } else {
    info = `${turn} it's your turn`;
  }

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <div className="gameInfo">{info}</div>
      <ul className="history-dropdown"> Go to move {historyList}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Every time I click a list item to call handleHistory it doesn't take effect until the second click

I have a code sample here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/q75y24qj49?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two small issues, that need to be fixed. You got React part correct. The issues are :

1. In your handle click, you need to create a new array, instead of using the old one.
2. slice params need to be different in handle history to get desired output.

Have added comments in your code for understanding. Hope it will be helpful to you.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React


const App = props => {
  const [turn, setTurn] = useState("X");
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([Array(9).fill(null)]);
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState(null);

  const latestBoard = history[history.length - 1];

  const handleClick = i => {
    if (latestBoard[i] !== null) {
      return;
    }
    //latestBoard.splice(i, 1, turn);
    //setHistory([...history, [...latestBoard]]);
    // latestBoard and history are same
    // reference hence you are spreading the same array
    // you need to do something like this below
    const copylatestBoard = [...latestBoard]; // Because array are passed by
    // reference 1st change
    copylatestBoard.splice(i, 1, turn); // 2nd change

    setHistory([...history, [...copylatestBoard]]); //3rd change
    setTurn(turn === "O" ? "X" : "O");
  };

  const handleHistory = index => {
    // if (index === 1) {
    //   setHistory([Array(9).fill(null)]);
    //   return;
    // }
    let newHistory = history.slice(0, index + 1); // need to be index + 1 to slice desired
    // as history at 0 is blank board. I am sure it will be obvious now
    setHistory(newHistory);
  };

  const calcWinner = squares => {
    /*...*/
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <GameBoard onClick={idx => handleClick(idx)} squares={latestBoard} />
      <Sidebar
        turn={turn}
        history={history}
        goBack={idx => handleHistory(idx)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const GameBoard = ({ squares, onClick }) => {
  const grid = squares.map((item, idx) => {
    return (
      <div key={idx} onClick={() => onClick(idx)}>
        {item}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div className="grid-container">{grid}</div>;
};

const Sidebar = ({ winner, turn, history, goBack }) => {
  let historyList = history.map((pos, idx) => {
    return idx >= 1 ? ( // to start after the first click
      <li key={idx} onClick={() => goBack(idx)}>
        {idx}
      </li>
    ) : null;
  });

  let info;

  if (winner) {
    info = `The winner is ${winner}`;
  } else {
    info = `${turn} it's your turn`;
  }

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <div className="gameInfo">{info}</div>
      <ul className="history-dropdown"> Go to move {historyList}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
 .container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25em;
  height: 90vh;
  max-height: 18em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
 .container > * {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
}
 .grid-container {
  flex: 5;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: ". . ." ". . ." ". . .";
  position: relative;
  height: 80%;
}
 .grid-container > * {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
 .grid-container > *:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
 .sidebar {
  padding: 1em;
}
 .sidebar .history-dropdown {
  transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
}
 .sidebar .history-dropdown > *:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```